# Running Craft Console Commands on Webfaction

Tags: console, commands

I'm trying to run a few of Craft's console commands on a Webfaction server to automate running Craft migrations and resolving Project Config changes, and it's throwing an error.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
php craft migrate/all
php craft project-config/sync
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this was a problem with running the right version of PHP. I was able to fix the issue by changing my command from `php` to `php74`, directly specifying the version of PHP that I want to run. This should work with `php71` `php73` and future versions like `php80` too.

Here's what my commands look like now:

```
php74 craft migrate/all
php74 craft project-config/sync
```